# loop list of input checkbox and get values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I am trying to get a table of names checked,
and send this array to a PHP page.

But I dont know how, I began by this code:

```
$(".ok").click(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
        var tt = $(this).val();
        alert(tt);
    }); 
});
```

---

```
echo "<table>";

foreach ($result as $data) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value='$data[0]' /></td><td>$data[0]</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try..

```
$(".ok").click(function(){
  //check if any are checked and if so redirect..
  if($("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length > 0)
    window.location.href = 'page.php?'+$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").serialize();
});
```

then in page.php..

```
$result = $_GET;
if(count($result)){
  foreach($result as $data){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value='$data' /></td><td>$data</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
}
```